# Gitlab CI to move files from build server to remote server(environment)

Tags: .net, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have created a `Gitlab CI` pipeline for my test project. The build part i have managed to do it. But i'm not sure how to do deployment part as my build runs on the Runner and Code/file needs to be moved to **Remote server (EC2)**. Here is my yaml file.

[image]

I know that in `Octopus deploy` we used to set up the environment and configure the machine for each of this environment. But i'm not sure how to do it using Gitlab CI.

Could anyone please help .

Answer (score 2):

One of the last stages in a pipeline should be the deployment of your app. In my opinion, the deployment stage should be just what you do to send what you have accomplished to a production environment.

After your build stage, you should have a folder where your built application should be prepared. For instance a 'dist' or 'bin' folder. Depending on your OS you could use commands like ***robocopy/xcopy/copy*** in windows instances - recommend using robocopy, or in Linux instances, you could use ***rsync***, for example. Also consider commands like ***SCP***, depending on your infrastructure.

Do you use .NET Core? You could also use ***dotnet publish*** command. Like the imagem [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1tDE.png)

[Example of 'dotnet publish'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1tDE.png)

Another example of robocopy in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0ass.png)

[Example of deployment with robocopy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0ass.png)

The pipeline variable 'ENVIRONMENT_INTEGRATION' is the path for the 'integration' environment.

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21.
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx

ps: unfortunatelly I can't add images to the post =/